# Simple Form: How can I create a custom wrapper that does not wrap the input and create a label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Within a simple_form custom wrapper, can you generate an input field without a wrapper and a its corresponding label?

Currently, my custom wrapper looks like this:

```
config.wrappers :category_tab, tag: "ul", class: "inline-list" do |ul|                                                                                                                         
  ul.use :html5                                                                                                                                                                             
  ul.wrapper tag: "li" do |li|                                                                                                                                                              
    li.wrapper tag: "label", class: "faux-tab" do |label|                                                                                                                                     
      label.use :input, label: false                                                                                                                                                          
      label.use :label_text, wrap_with: { tag: "span", class: "label-text" }
    end    
  end                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

I'm attempting to output the HTML structure below

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"></input>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The current output is:

```
<ul class="inline-list radio_buttons optional search_category">
  <li>
    <label class="faux-tab">
      <span class="radio">
        <input checked="checked" class="radio_buttons optional" id="search_category_" name="search[category]" type="radio" value="">
        <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="search_category_">All</label>
      </span>
      <span class="label-text">Category</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I believe what your looking for is input_field vs input.  That should give you the input without the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

It is a configuration in the `simple_form.rb`. Find this line, and be sure, that the value of the `boolean_style` is `:inline`.

`# Define the way to render check boxes / radio buttons with labels.
 # Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
 #   inline: input + label
 #   nested: label > input
 config.boolean_style = :inline`

Answer (score 0):

This code below may result in your expected HTML:

```
config.wrappers :category_tab, tag: "ul" do |ul|
  ul.use :html5
  ul.wrapper tag: "li" do |li|
    li.wrapper tag: "label" do |label|
      label.use :input, label: false 
    end    
  end
end
```